# Line $L$ is tangent to $f(x)=x^4+2x^3−11x^2−13x+35$ at $x=p$ and $x=q$. Find the equation of $L$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> **Question:** Line $L$ is tangent to $f(x)=x^4+2x^3−11x^2−13x+35$ at $x=p$ and $x=q$. Find the equation of $L$.

I'm not allowed to graph or use a calculator. I believe I am allowed to assume for this question that both tangents are the same line, and that $x=p$ and $x=q$ are the turning points. (Checking Desmos confirms this, and that $L= -x-1$)

I got that $f(x) - L = (x-p)^2(x-q)^2$, but I'm not sure how I would find $p$ or $q$ without graphing, and I'm pretty sure I need that to solve for $L$. Can someone point me in the right direction? I'm pretty sure this has an easy solution, but I just can't see it.

Comment: if you take derivative of $f$ and plug in $x=p, x=q$ you'll get two points that belong to the line.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't learned how to take derivatives yet, so I don't think that's what I'm supposed to do.

Comment: expand  $f(x)-(a x+b)-(x-p)^2(x-q)^2=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}(x-p)^2(x-q)^2&=&(x^2-2px+p^2)(x^2-2qx+q^2)\\&=&x^4-2(p+q)x^3+(p^2+4pq+q^2)x^2+(\ldots)x+(\ldots)\end{array}$$

So, if we can fit $p$, $q$ so that the coefficients of $2$nd, $3$rd and $4$th degree fit, then $L$ will do the rest of the job, as it is linear - it can be tailored to produce the correct coefficient of degree $0$ and $1$.

Thus, you only need to solve:

$$p+q=-1$$
$$p^2+4pq+q^2=-11$$

From the second equation you get that $(p+q)^2+2pq=-11$, i.e. $pq=-6$, and then Vieta formulas tell you that $p,q$ are the solutions of the equation $x^2+x-6=0$, i.e. $p,q=2,-3$ in some order.

Now, knowing $p$ and $q$, you can easily determine the equation for the line $L$.

Comment: Thanks, that's just what I was looking for.